# Сын Батыя — принявший христианство Сартак, (—) который... Снимается ли второе тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, приложение, тире

*Сын Батыя — принявший христианство Сартак, (—) который занимался в Орде русскими делами...*

- Можно ли обособить приложение запятыми: будет ли хуже восприниматься фраза? *Сын Батыя, принявший христианство Сартак, который занимался в Орде русскимим делами...*

Comment: Обособить запятыми — самое то!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чего громоздить знаки, если можно распрекрасно обойтись без?

Мне "смотрится" первое тире и не мешает отсутствие второго: там же просто замечательно утрясённое согласование: *Сартак, который...*

***Сын Батыя — принявший христианство Сартак, который занимался в Орде русскими делами...***

А запятые только воду замутят, кто там на ком стоял.

Comment: Нужно видеть все предложение. Если поставить точку после "делами", то получится ерунда, совсем другой смысл.

Comment: Я подозревала вот такой: ***Сын Батыя — принявший христианство Сартак, который занимался в Орде русскими делами, проявлял ну прямо таки  жуткую толерантность и веротерпимость.***

Comment: Согласен, читается хорошо, но научите, как доказать, что можно одним тире обойтись.